# R Code Categorical Variable to 1 and 0

Tags: r, binary

Is there an easy way to convert  2 level categorical variables to binary and then change the column name? So for example: if I had 'gender' variable how would I easily code female as 1, male as 0, and change the column name to isFemale? Thank you in advance.

Comment: One approach is `yourdata$isFemale <- as.integer(yourdata$yourvariable == "female")`  There would be several dupes for this question

Comment: If it's already a `factor` class, then `as.integer(yourdata$yourcolumn)` or `as.numeric(yourdata$yourcolumn)` will work. As for changing column names, please see introductory material available such as that available at the [R tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(Lett=letters[1:6], Gender = c("F","M","M","M","F","M"))
df
#   Lett Gender
# 1    a      F
# 2    b      M
# 3    c      M
# 4    d      M
# 5    e      F
# 6    f      M



levels(df$Gender) <- c(1,0)
df
#   Lett Gender
# 1    a      1
# 2    b      0
# 3    c      0
# 4    d      0
# 5    e      1
# 6    f      0

names(df)[2] <- "isFemale"
df
#   Lett isFemale
# 1    a        1
# 2    b        0
# 3    c        0
# 4    d        0
# 5    e        1
# 6    f        0
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to create a new column and convert gender variable to numeric

lets say your data = data, and gender variable =sex

```
       data$sex <- as.factor (data$sex) 
       data$isFemale<- as.numeric (data$sex)
```